# Is it possible to manually update a join table when using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, join

I have a hibernate many-to-many mapping of 2 tables users and teams.  This creates a join table of users_teams which contains the user id and team id mapping.  I would like to be able to update both users and teams using only the join table i.e. Given that I know the user id and team id I want to just insert those id's into the join table.  I tried this but it does not work.  Is this even possible?  The reason for wanting to do this is because the DTO's will only have id's and not the full objects for performance reasons.

Comment: What does "I tried this but it does not work" mean? Of course it is possible. Hibernate fetches the information about the relation from the linking table. Please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot insert foreign keys directly in the join table using "normal" session (or entity manager) operations (like save,update etc) by using just the id's because of maintaining the relationship ( via foreign keys) is the responsibility of Hibernate and Hibernate gets this information from your mapped entities and your mapped entities maintain the relationship through references to objects and not their id's.

You can however insert id' using native query feature where you can write the insert sql and pass parameters. For e.g., with Hibernate session you can use

```
session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO USERS_TEAMS (USERID,TEAMID) VALUES(?,?)");
```

or

```
entitymanager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO USERS_TEAMS (USERID,TEAMID) VALUES(?,?)")
```